# Is that possible to export Class and Function in the same file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Current code:

```
class Test {
  doOne = async () => {
    ...
  };
}

module.exports = new Test();
```

I want something like this:

```
class Test {
  doOne = async () => {
    ...
  };
}

const testOne = async () => {
  ...
}

module.exports = new Test();
```

How can I export `testOne` function? Is that possible to export both class `Test` and function `testOne`?

Comment: Just write `exports.Test = Test;` and `exports.testOne = testOne;`.

Comment: Btw, you should not export a `new Test` instance when you actually want to export the class. Or if you want to export an object, then you should not use `class` syntax, just create an object.

Comment: I need both class and function in same file. That function is used inside the class as well as some other files. So I want to make a stand-alone function for that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need export an object with `class` and `function` properties.

```js
class Test {
  doOne = async () => {
    ...
  };
}

const testOne = async () => {
  ...
}

module.exports = {
  test: new Test(),
  testOne,
}
```